# Mule ESB 3.4.x: Multiple https clients with client certificate doesn't work togheter

Tags: ssl, mule, transport

I've got two mule apps. Let me call it APP1, APP2. APP1 and APP2 are using some soap web services (different) using client certificate authentication.

- APP1 works fine if deployed standalone
- APP2 works fine if deployed standalone
- APP1 APP2 doens't work togheter. It seems the first APP loaded work, the second no. By working I mean the external ws connetions using client certificate.

All in all it seems that you can't have two apps on the same server that uses client cert auth, 
because only on write variable on jvm. The issue is that these application should not be write 
in jvm variables own certificate info.

Here there are the jvm configuration at runtime

```
root@icef-servizi-1 apps.deploy]# /opt/java/bin/jinfo -sysprops 23598 | grep ssl
Attaching to process ID 23598, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 23.21-b01
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword = xxxxxxxxxxx
javax.net.ssl.trustManagerAlgorithm = SunX509
javax.net.ssl.keyStore = /opt/mule-standalone-3.4.0/apps/ESB_ICEFCud/classes/keystore/client-p.icef-to-wsfis.intra.infotn.it.jks
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType = jks
java.protocol.handler.pkgs = com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol|org.apache.axis.transport|
com.sun.net.ssl.enableECC = false
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType = jks
javax.net.ssl.trustStore = /opt/mule-standalone-3.4.0/apps/ESB_ICEFCud/classes/keystore/client-p.icef-to-wsfis.intra.infotn.it.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword = xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Any idea/workaround? This the configuration of APPA, APPB

APPA

```
<https:connector name="Https_Pi3_InfoTn" cookieSpec="netscape"
        validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0"
        receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="${ws.https.connector.client.timeout}"
        serverSoTimeout="${ws.https.connector.server.timeout}" socketSoLinger="0"
        doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS" enableCookies="false">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
    <https:tls-client path="${ws.https.certificate.file}" storePassword="${ws.https.certificate.password}" />
    <https:tls-key-store path="${ws.https.certificate.file}" keyPassword="${ws.https.certificate.password}" storePassword="${ws.https.certificate.password}" />
    <https:tls-server path="${ws.https.certificate.file}" storePassword="${ws.https.certificate.password}" />
</https:connector>
<sub-flow name="GetActiveClassificationScheme_WS" doc:name="GetActiveClassificationScheme_WS">
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="GetActiveClassificationScheme"
        clientClass="com.nttdata._2012.pi3.ClassificationSchemes" port="BasicHttpBinding_IClassificationSchemes"
        wsdlLocation="https://${ws.host}:${ws.port}/${ws.path.classificationschemes}"
        doc:name="Prepare messaggio SOAP2">
    </cxf:jaxws-client>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        doc:name="Chiama WS" connector-ref="Https_Pi3_InfoTn" method="POST"
        host="${ws.host}" path="${ws.path.router}" port="${ws.port}"
        responseTimeout="${ws.https.connector.response.timeout}" />
</sub-flow>
```

APPB

```
<https:connector name="Https_Cud_InfoTn" enableCookies="true" cookieSpec="netscape" 
    validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" 
    receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" 
    clientSoTimeout="${ws.https.connector.client.timeout}" serverSoTimeout="${ws.https.connector.server.timeout}" 
    socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
    <https:tls-client path="${ws.https.certificate.file}" storePassword="${ws.https.certificate.password}"/>
    <https:tls-key-store path="${ws.https.certificate.file}" keyPassword="${ws.https.certificate.password}" storePassword="${ws.https.certificate.password}"/>
    <https:tls-server path="${ws.https.certificate.file}" storePassword="${ws.https.certificate.password}"/>
</https:connector>
<sub-flow name="RichiestaRiferimCud_WS" doc:name="RichiestaRiferimCud_WS">
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="CercaRiferimentiCud" clientClass="infotn._2008.richiestacud.FISServiceServiceagent" port="CudServiceEndpoint1" wsdlLocation="https://${ws.host}:${ws.port}/${ws.path.wsdl}?wsdl" doc:name="Prepare messaggio SOAP2"/>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${ws.host}" port="${ws.port}" path="${ws.path.cud}" method="POST" responseTimeout="${ws.https.connector.response.timeout}" connector-ref="Https_Cud_InfoTn" doc:name="Chiama WS"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Comment: One workaround is to import both certificates into the same store.

Comment: Yes this should work.

Comment: No it doesn't work, I can't have a single store cause each certificate  have a different private password an it seems that in jks you need to have the jks store password equals to the certificate private one. So only on private key can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Define explicitly the keystore and the truststore for the HTTPS connectors for both applications, even if they're using Java's cacerts.

This will still override the system properties for SSL but it will use a different SSL context for each application.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are meaning by explicitly. 
The https connectors defined in APPA and in APPB are distinct https connectors with its own ssl/tls settings. There is nothing defined by me in jvm.
What should I do?
`code`
<https:tls-client 
<https:tls-key-store 
<https:tls-server 
`code`

Comment: Can you update your post putting both configurations?

Comment: Ok post is updated. There are two https connectors (APPA and APPB) and its own https:outbound-endpoint